# getting error - > TypeError : user.generateAuthToken is not a function -

Tags: node.js, jwt

```
user.js__

const config = require('config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const  mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require('joi'); 

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {     
        type : String,
        required  : true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 50
    },
    email : {     
        type : String,
        required  : true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 50,
        unique : true
    },
    password : {     
        type : String,
        required  : true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 1024,
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: this._id}, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    return token;
}

function validateUser(user){
    const schema = {
        name     : Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email    : Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password : Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
    };
    return Joi.validate(user,schema);
}

exports.User = User;
exports.validate =  validateUser;
```

```
users.js>__

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const _ = require('lodash');
const {User, validate} = require('../models/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require('joi');
const router  = express.Router();

router.post('/', async(req,res) => {

    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let user = await User.findOne({email : req.body.email});
    if(user) return res.status(400).send('User already registered.');

    user = new User(_.pick( req.body , ["name","email","password"]));
    const salt    = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password , salt);

    await user.save();

    const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    res.send(token);
    res.header('x-auth-token',token).send(_.pick(user,['_id','name','email']));
});

module.exports = router;
```

*rest part of my application is working fine but while i am generating auth token, i am getting error. Any body please let me know what i am missing.*
I have postel my model(user.js) and routes(users.js).

is it possible i am getting this error because of installing any old dependencies ?

please see my code and let me know.

Comment: please give more details

Comment: Try printing user object to see if it has generateAuthToken method.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya no, still the same error.

Comment: What user object is printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to give more code because we can't see your Schema. I think you are doing it little wrong. When you are creating your schema, pass this schema to model. I am not sure if you are using any ORM like mongoose.

```
const userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const newUser = new userModel();

//now try to run the method on model

const token = newUser.generateAuthToken();
```

You can check more on this :

https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-add-instance-methods-with-mongoose-236

```
user.js__

const config = require('config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const  mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require('joi'); 

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {     
        type : String,
        required  : true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 50
    },
    email : {     
        type : String,
        required  : true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 50,
        unique : true
    },
    password : {     
        type : String,
        required  : true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 1024,
    }
});

// first assign method and then create model from it
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: this._id}, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    return token;
}

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

function validateUser(user){
    const schema = {
        name     : Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email    : Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password : Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
    };
    return Joi.validate(user,schema);
}

exports.User = User;
exports.validate =  validateUser;
```

Comment: I have just made a change in it. please try to run this way.

Comment: OH yes, I have made a big mistake there. Thank you. you save my time.